# When data_replication_factor is set to 2, why did all 3 datanodes in Apache IoTDB are all writing new data?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

There is a strange problem I encountered. I deployed Apache IoTDB cluster with 1C3D (1 ConfigNode and 3 DataNodes). During the pressure testing, I observed that the new data was written to all three DataNodes. I am confused, since the current `data_replication_factor` is set to 2, should there only be two nodes with data written? Why did all three DataNodes are all accepting data? Should I consider this abnormal and if so, what should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache IoTDB, data is fragmented not by DataNode, but by DataRegion. The data will be dvided based on time series partition and time partitions. Alos, during cluster expansion of IoTDB, the number of regions may also increases to fully exploit the computational resources of all nodes without manual intervention. Therefore, as long as all your data are successfully inserted into IoTDB, the case you observed is normal.